# Convert single row to multiple rows in Power BI based a date column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to convert the data as per below requirement in Power BI:

Getting the source file like below:

[image]

Need to convert each row into multiple rows based on the number of projection months (column 4) for each month. Expense month below is 1st of every month. Then divide the expense by projection month for each month planned expense.

[image]

How do I achieve this in Power BI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this transformation in the power query editor. Here below is the transformation code-

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUXJ0cgaSRgZGhroGlrpGBkCOGQgbKMXqRCsZAZkurm5wFWa6BiBNpkBsDFFhDGRGREbBVVhAVFiAVBgpxcYCAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, Title = _t, #"Project Start Date" = _t, #"Project Months" = _t, Expense = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Title", type text}, {"Project Start Date", type date}, {"Project Months", Int64.Type}, {"Expense", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Calculated Start of Month" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Project Start Date", Date.StartOfMonth, type date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Calculated Start of Month", "Custom", each List.Range({1..[Project Months]},0)),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each [Expense]/[Project Months]),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom"),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Custom.2", each Date.AddMonths([Project Start Date],[Custom]-1)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Project Start Date", "Project Months", "Expense", "Custom"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom.2", "Expense Month"}, {"Custom.1", "Planned Expense"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: I need to something like this...I already have a table 'Programs' from an Excel file with many columns, I need a new table that has one or more rows per program for each year from program start to program end -- so if start is 2/20/2020 and end 2/4/2022, I need a record with program id and year - so 3 records...I don't know how to modify your code to do this...